# Limit mysql insert value by trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a trigger to prevent empty string insert for cname column and values smaller than 7000 and larger than 8000 for empno column by making it null. Here is how I have done it:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER test1
BEFORE insert
ON clients
FOR EACH row BEGIN
if new.cname = '' THEN
SET new.cname = null; 
if new.empno <7000 THEN
SET new.empno = null;
if new.empno>8000 THEN
SET new.empno = null;
end if;
end if;
end if;
end;
```

The cname column works fine. But the empno will accept anything and I cannot figure why. My table is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE clients
(
empno     INTEGER     NOT NULL DEFAULT 7654                   
cname   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set each end if after the corresponding if:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER test1
BEFORE insert
ON clients
FOR EACH row BEGIN
if new.cname = '' THEN
SET new.cname = null;
end if;
if new.empno <7000 THEN
SET new.empno = null;
end if;
if new.empno>8000 THEN
SET new.empno = null;
end if;
end;
```